# How to correctly configure multiple constructors?

Tags: java, multiple-inheritance, multiple-constructors

I'm doing an assignment based around inheritance and I have created 2 constructors that are suppose to do different things. One constructor does not have any parameters and should produce a pre-defined value, the other constructor has 2 parameters which consist of a name and an age of types String and int. I have somehow reconfigured the two constructors so that they both do not produce what they should be. Here is the classes that these constructors are invoked in:

**Animal (super class)**

```
abstract public class Animal implements Comparable<Animal>
{
    int age;
    String name;

    Animal(String name, int age)   
    {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    } 

    Animal()
    {   
         this("newborn", 0);
    }        

    public int getAge()
    {
         return age;
    }

    public void setName(String newName)
    {
        name = newName;
    }

    String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

**Carnivore**

```
public class Carnivore extends Animal
{
    Carnivore(String name, int age)   
    {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }

    Carnivore()
    {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Animal o)
    {
        //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
    }
}
```

**Wolf**

```
public class Wolf extends Carnivore
{
    String name;
    int age;

    Wolf(String name, int age)   
    {  
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    Wolf()
    {
        super();
    }   

    String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

**Main method**

```
System.out.println("************1st constructor of Wolf************");
Wolf wolfExample = new Wolf("Bob", 2) {};        
System.out.println("Name = " + wolfExample.getName());
System.out.println("Age = " + wolfExample.getAge());

System.out.println("************2nd constructor of Wolf************");    
Wolf newWolf = new Wolf();
System.out.println("Name = " + newWolf.getName());
System.out.println("Age = " + newWolf.getAge());
```

**Actual Output**

```
************1st constructor of Wolf************
Name = Bob
Age = 0
************2nd constructor of Wolf************
Name = null
Age = 0
```

**Expected Output**

```
************1st constructor of Wolf************
Name = Bob
Age = 2
************2nd constructor of Wolf************
Name = newborn
Age = 0
```

The ages are returning their default value and the name for the second constructor is also returning null but I'm not too sure why. This is my first time working with multiple constructors so I'm a little confused as to ow it works so any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please look at posting a [MCVE] for quicker help!

Comment: this is what you are doing `this("newborn", 0);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your base class seems correct, but you need to change your implementations.

Your `Wolf` and `Carnivore` constructors should be:

```
Wolf(String name, int age)   
{
    super(name, age);
}
```

Reason being, you are setting the *local* instance variables for each type, but calling `getAge()` method of the super class - this is getting the super's value of `age`, whose's value has not actually been assigned anywhere, and is given a default value of *0*. This goes the same for `name`, which defaults to *null*.

You need to call `super` with the passed variables, and do not need to redefine them for each extended object.

Comment: ahahah, I was just rereading through _everything_ to see why it would not have based on your last comment ;) glad to hear it, happy coding! be sure to upvote / accept helpful answers :)

Comment: know that you do not need to override `getName` in _Wolf_either, calling it on this object will use the method / variable value defined in the base class.

Comment: Yeah I realized the same thing when I went through that class again and just deleted that method xD Thanks for your help, I up-voted and picked yours as the best answer.

Comment: @Matt Clark The *Wolf* inherit *Animal* then it should have its own *getAge method* although it dont override this method,**but** then why wolf.getAge return the age of Animal, I cant figure out. And if I remove the filed variable *age* and *name* in **Wolf** and so *Wolf* inherit filed of *Animal* it will output what **OP** expect, maybe when inherit filed both parent and children's filed variable is the *same memory*? can you give me some explanation or relevant link?