# How to remove errors from the ouput of a program?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

So I have written a program tat outputs as I want it to correctly but for some reason I am still getting some errors at the end of the program which I'd prefer not to be shown. I've tried using `Systematize(out);` but all this does is change the color of the errors from red to the same color as the rest of the program. Here is the output of the program:

```
************Wolf"************
Name = Bob
Age = 2
Noise = Woof!
************Parrot************
Parrot's name = Polly
Age = 6
Noise = Argh!
************Exception examples************
java.lang.Exception: Carnivores only eat meat!
Exception caught above
Exception caught below
java.lang.Exception: Herbivores only eat plants!
************Herbivore non-caught Exception example************
Herbivores eat Vegetables
************Carnivore non-caught Exception example************
Carnivores eat Steak
************Omnivore eating habbit************
Omniivores eat meat or fruit and vegertables
************New herbivore animal************
Parrot's name = Haryy
Age = 2
Noise = Squeek!
************Animal being fed************
Wolf has eaten 10 times
************New wolf creation************
Name = newborn
Age = 0
************ArrayList before sorting************
Sam,5
************ArrayList after sorting************
Pat,10
Wesley,7
Sam,5
George,3
Wesley,7
************ArrayList after sorting************
Pat,10
Wesley,7
Sam,5
George,3
Sam,5
************ArrayList after sorting************
Pat,10
Wesley,7
Sam,5
George,3
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
George,3
************ArrayList after sorting************
Pat,10
Wesley,7
Sam,5
George,3
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1380)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachOrdered(ReferencePipeline.java:423)
    at QuestionEditor.Main.main(Main.java:124)
C:\Users\lee-pc\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Here is the main method that outputs the part that contains errors:

```
   Demo.main(args); // populate the ArrayList in Demo Class main method 2.
    ArrayList<Animal> animalGroup = Demo.animalGroup; // Retrieve the ArrayList in Demo class.
    animalGroup.stream().map((animal) -> {
        System.out.println(animal.getName()+","+animal.getAge());
            return animal;
        }).map((Animal _item) -> {
            System.out.println("************ArrayList after sorting************");
            return _item;
        }).map((Animal _item) -> {
            Collections.sort(animalGroup,new AgeComparator()); // Sort highest to lowest
            return _item;
        }).forEachOrdered((Animal _item) -> {
            animalGroup.forEach((animal2) -> {
                System.out.println(animal2.getName() + "," + animal2.getAge());
            });
        });
```

Does anybody know why this is happening? And what is the best way of resolving this issue? Thanks for any feedback, much appreciated.

Comment: Might [you two](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40837996/1790644) be in the same class?

Comment: Which line is `Main.java:124` ?

Comment: Yeah we're in the same class haha

Comment: That is `}).forEachOrdered((Animal _item) -> {`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Collections.sort` modifies the content of `animalGroup` if there are any elements not in sorted order.
You are doing this in the middle of iterating over `animalGroup`.
If while iterating over the list some elements get swapped,
the outcome would be a mess.
For this reason it is forbidden to modify a list while iterating over it,
hence the `ConcurrentModificationException`.
This is known as the *fail-fast* policy of collection implementations in Java,
you can read more about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html).

What you're doing with the streams doesn't make a lot of sense.
It seems you're looking for this:

```
List<Animal> animalGroup = Demo.animalGroup; 

animalGroup.forEach(animal -> System.out.println(animal.getName() + "," + animal.getAge()));

System.out.println("************ArrayList after sorting************");

Collections.sort(animalGroup, new AgeComparator()); // Sort highest to lowest

animalGroup.forEach(animal -> System.out.println(animal.getName() + "," + animal.getAge()));
```

Comment: When I compile this, I get one error which says `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at QuestionEditor.Main.main(Main.java:115)` Line 115 is `animalGroup.forEach(animal -> System.out.println(animal.getName() + "," + animal.getAge()));`I'm not too sure this would be returning null?

Comment: Either `animalGroup` is `null` or it contains some elements that are `null`. That's most probably a different bug somewhere else in your program.